# update sql query excluding those in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-7

I have two tables, pricelist.plpart and bsp_priceupdate.xplpart

all prices in pricelist table need to be updated with 3% EXCLUDING those in the bsp_priceupdate table.

i will be running this update in sql 7.

Appreciate your help.

D

Comment: Hi, The query will run on SQL 7 server.

Comment: Something like UPDATE TBL1 set FLD1=3 WHERE EXISTS (Select 1 from TBL2...etc. ...)

Comment: I was thinking of something like:   update pricelist set plunitprice = plunitprice + (plunitprice *.03)
where pricelist.plpart <> bsp_priceupdate.xplpart

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this ought to do it...

```
UPDATE pricelist.plpart
SET price = ROUND( price * 1.03, 2 )
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM bsp_priceupdate.xplpart
    WHERE bsp_priceupdate.xplpart.partID = pricelist.plpart.partID )
```

Comment: how do i round the updated prices to 2 decimal places.  3.333 to 3.33

Comment: I updated my answer to include the `ROUND` function.